# can a Try Catch work within a Catch

Tags: php, try-catch

i've got a try catch in the framework i'm using which when the catch is triggered it displays an error report page, one thing in this report page is that it displays a menu where the times came from the database

what i thought it's do is that i'd put another try catch in the catch in case if the database can be connected to, something like this

```
try
{
    code that would throw an excpetion
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    try
    {
        connect to database
        run query
        log error in database
        output screen using database data
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        output screen using static html
    }
}
```

this way if the exception was a database connection error it will use a static html output rather than the dynamic one generated from database data

however when i cause a database error (deleting a required table) my static html doesn't work

i am wondering if it is even possible for a try catch to work in the catch or weather it's the framework (i'm using magento), i ask this because if it is possible to be done then i'll spend time figuring out why the framework is stopping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to put a try/catch block in a catch block.

However, from your description, it sounds like you want more 'intelligent' exception catching. You can do something like this:

```
try {
    // some operations including something with a database
}
catch (DatabaseException $e) {
    // the exception thrown by the code above was a DatabaseException
    // output some error message without using the database
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    // the exception thrown by the code above could have been any type of exception EXCEPT a DatabaseException
    // so you can still try to use the database to compose the error message
}
```

Note that anything that can throw exceptions can also throw these exceptions when run from a catch block. For example, when the try block throws an exception *before* it reaches any database code, a database exception can still occur when handling the original, non-database, exception.